# Turn off ms-files.php after network setup

Tags: multisite, uploads

I have a multisite that was set up on WordPress 3.4. That means that uploads for sub-sites are stored in `wp-content/blogs.dir/{blog_id}/files` and are served through ms-files.php.

In WordPress 3.5, ms-files.php was [disbanded completely](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/19235) for new installs and uploads are stored and accessed at `wp-content/uploads/sites/{blog_id}`.

Is there anyway I can switch my install from the pre-3.5 way of serving/uploading files to the new way? I would like to continue serving uploads through `files/` for current blogs, if possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In theory:

1. Move images from blogs.dir/SITENUM/files/ to /uploads/SITENUM/ (or make an alias)
2. Edit all sites so they don't look in /files/ but in /uploads/SITENUM/
3. .htaccess, remove the ms-files.php line
4. Search/replace each posts table for each site, changing /files/ to /uploads/SITENUM/

A walk-through can be found [here (dumping ms-files)](http://halfelf.org/2012/dumping-ms-files/), this is not a trivial hack! It involves command-line usage, sql, and using a mu-plugin.

### Resources

- [wp.org/support/removing-ms-filesphp-after-upgrading-existing-multisite-to-35](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/removing-ms-filesphp-after-upgrading-existing-multisite-to-35)
- [wp.org/support/remove-ms-files-rewriting](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/remove-ms-files-rewriting)
- [Dumping ms-files](http://halfelf.org/2012/dumping-ms-files/)

Comment: May I recommend editing the chosen answer to suggest `/uploads/sites/SITENUM` to stay coherent with upstream defaults?

Comment: There's an additional step: you should add `ms_files_rewriting` key with an empty value to `wp_sitemeta`. `site_id = 1`

Answer (score 1):

I just opened a ticket about supporting old /files/ links:
http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/23755#comment:1

There is a solution in that ticket which requiring editing ms-files. I am not happy with editing core but i dont wanna break any working sites with defining BLOGUPLOADDIR networkwide.
I hope it helps for old /files/ link and i hope we can find a better way without editing core.